# Checking if a String contains a String that follows a format using Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I was wondering if someone could help me with determining whether or not a string contains a certain regex.

This is what I have so far:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[[0-9]+\\-+[0-9]\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
System.out.println("" + matcher.matches());
```

This returns true if the message is something like "[1-3]" but not if it has other characters surrounding it. Also, I want to be able to get to the two values in the string too. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `whether or not a string contains a certain regex` --> What regex? `I want to be able to get to the two values in the string too` --> What values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This [does not work] if it has other characters surrounding it.

This is because `matches` looks for the regex to match the entire string. If you need to know if there's a partial match, use `find()` instead:

```
System.out.println("" + matcher.find());
```

> Also, I want to be able to get to the two values in the string too.

Make *capturing groups* around the numeric parts by adding parentheses:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([0-9]+)\\-+([0-9])\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Note that the second number will be a single-digit number, unless you put a `+` after square brackets the way you did in the expression that captures the first numeric group.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! :D Works perfectly from what I can see